# HTTP requests from React not reaching Express backend on production server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http, create-react-app

I have a React frontend (made with create-react-app) and an Express backend, with a remote MySQL database. Everything works fine when I run both locally, serving the frontend on `localhost:3000` and proxying http requests to `localhost:3306`, which is also the port that the Express app listens on. Requests are made to `localhost:3000/api/endpoint`, and again this works.

I'm now trying to move this setup over to production on my server. I'm using a shared server and Node is configured through Cpanel (although I do have SSH access). I'm not "running" the React side on the server the way I would in development, but rather have created build files and placed them in the directory corresponding to my domain homepage.

Let's say my domain is foo.com. I've been advised by my hosting company to run Node on port 50000 (as when I had tried 3306 it said it was already in use). Currently, every request to my API seems to result in a 404: it is attempting to query `foo.com/api/endpoint` and failing. My question is: how do I properly direct these requests to my backend? I know that the `proxy` option in React package.json isn't really meant to be used in production, so what should I use instead, and what should it be set to? Is there anything else I should expect to have to configure on the server?

---

**Update**

Ok, I'm now trying to bypass Cpanel's Node manager and run things manually. My document structure on the server is like this:

```
/home/user
|--- /project
|   |--- /backend
|       |--- (Node server.js, etc.)
|   |--- /client
|       |--- (React src, components, etc.)
|--- /public_html
    |--- (React build files)
    |--- .htaccess
```

I believe the React build files need to be in `public_html` for the server to render them on my homepage. Hence, I am currently **NOT** serving the build files from my backend (although @MattCarlotta has suggested that I do this below; I am open to doing this if it seems necessary. The React app itself seems to run ok live at 3ecologies-seedbank.com; but perhaps I also need to tell the Node server about the `public_html` location?).

Other resources have led me to think that part of the answer lies with the `.htaccess` file. Mine currently looks like this (including some Cpanel-generated code):

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/public_html$ http://127.0.0.1:50000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/public_html/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:50000/$1 [P,L]
```

My rough understanding of what this should do is redirect requests from the pages at `public_html` to my Node app, which is listening on port `50000`. This makes sense to me because when I run both the back and front locally, I need to proxy requests from `localhost:3000` (front) to `localhost:3306` (back).

I have started the Node app over SSH, with a simple `node server.js`. It is able to confirm that it is listening on port `50000` and connects to the database. However, every request made to the API from the front-end still results in a `404`. It seems to still not be reaching the back-end.

If it helps, I'm on a shared server with Apache 2.4.41 and Cpanel 82.0 (build 17).

---

**TL;DR**
What is the production equivalent of setting a `proxy` in React to send requests to a Node backend?

Comment: Run node on port `5000` and make sure your client-side requests aren't using `http://localhost:5000` and instead `http(s)://foo.com` during production. For example, I use `axios` and when I build my client-side, I have a configuration that adjusts the `baseUrl` depending on the env: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/Matts-Universe/blob/development/client/src/actions/axiosConfig.js. To make sure your requests are even reaching your server, I'd recommend using morgan as an express middleware: https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#expressconnect (if it hits the server, it logs the request).

Comment: @MattCarlotta Thanks. I am using `axios` too. What's weird is that the base URL for the requests being created does seem to be `http://example.com` (changed from "foo" to appease SO) in production. When I look at the `GET` request in chrome dev tools, that's what I see. So it seems to be sending it to the right domain, but I don't think it's actually reaching the Express server. (Continued in next comment below...)

Comment: This is the endpoint it's trying to hit on the backend:
`router.get('/verify', (req, res) => {

 const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

 if (!token) {

  res.status(401).json({ status: 'No token provided.' });

 } else {

  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, function(err, decoded) {

   if (err) {
          res.status(401).json({ status: 'Invalid token' });
        } else {
          res.status(200).json({ status: 'Token good!' });
   } 
  })
 }
});`
So the `404` result suggests to me that it's not reaching the backend.

Comment: Add morgan as an express middleware. If the request hits your backend, it'll show `GET /api/example (status) 123ms` in the console. That way, you can narrow down the problem to client or API. If you have a github repo, I can take a look, but otherwise it's a guessing game.

Comment: @MattCarlotta thanks. I've added morgan and it works when I run locally, outputting to my Terminal console. But how do I view the output from Chrome in production?

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty, you have several problems that were holding you back:

- You're using a `package.json` proxy that will only work in development. Instead use an `axios` [configuration](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/seedbank-example/blob/master/client/src/helpers/axiosConfig.js) on the client-side and [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) [configuration](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/seedbank-example/blob/master/anarchive/server.js#L21-L26) on the API side to allow both to communicate in development/production.
- Your `server.js` isn't serving your client `build` production assets, so I included an [example](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/seedbank-example/blob/master/anarchive/server.js#L66-L77) of how to do so. In addition, I added a `production` script in anarchive's [package.json](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/seedbank-example/blob/master/anarchive/package.json#L12) to create a working local production example. Simply type `npm run production` or `yarn production` to run the example. In this simple example, go to localhost:5000, and the client will immediately attempt to verify a fake JWT token by invoking an [IFFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) found [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/seedbank-example/blob/master/client/src/components/AuthTest.js). The API will receive the token, authenticate it, then respond back with an "Invalid token" alert.
- I couldn't get your API route configuration to work, so I'd recommend a more standard approach.

For example:

```
const authRoutes = require("./routes/api/auth");

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
```

or

```
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/api/auth"));
```

Doing the above should get you up and running.

**Here's a working repo**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/seedbank-example

---

Some other notes...

You can simplify a lot of your API controller code by using `async/await` and `try/catch` blocks. For example, [this](https://github.com/senselab-3e/seedbank/blob/master/anarchive/routes/api/auth.js#L11-L24) -- which currently crashes your app if a header doesn't contain an authorization) -- can be simplified to [this](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/seedbank-example/blob/master/anarchive/routes/api/auth.js#L11-L26) (unfortunately JWT uses callbacks instead of promises, so I wrapped it in a promise for cleanliness -- but the main point being that the `verify` controller is much easier to read and catches any errors and sends them back to the client, instead of crashing your app).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This feels super on the right track, but I'm still having trouble getting it up and running in production. I'm adding an update to the original post to reflect the current status.

Comment: It seems that it's somehow still not reaching the backend on my production server. (Separate minor issue is that I don't know how to access process.env on the client side, so it's broken locally now too. But I can find a way around that.) I'm happy to provide any more info that would be helpful.

Comment: Re the build assets though, I actually should have mentioned that on my production server, I have the build files copied over to a `public_html` folder in Cpanel that corresponds to the homepage at 3ecologies-seedbank.com. So perhaps they don't actually need to be served up by Node as in your example? Sorry, I realize this is a lot; I'm a novice in this area and porting this over to Cpanel has been a nightmare.

Comment: Sometimes the service worker can mess with production builds. If you're using chrome, open an incognito tab and try again (else clear browser cache). Unfortunately, I've never used cpanel, so I can't be much help there. That said, if it works in a local production (like my example), then the problem lies within your production server setup.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a stripped down app that just utilizes an IFFE to make a call to the API and the API responds back with a message. Bare essentials for the front and back-end. Rule out as many variables as possible. Then attempt to make that stripped down example work in a remote production.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the original post. I do think the issue is with the production server setup, or rather with how my app interacts with that setup.

Comment: Hey man, I am facing almost same issue as I am trying to store auth token on successful login to create session but with even your suggested method it doesn't store it
If you have a moment kindly check this question that i have posted.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70636002/httponly-cookies-not-being-stored-when-app-deployed-on-cpanel