# Httponly cookies not being stored when app deployed on Cpanel

Tags: reactjs, cpanel

Httponly cookies are not being set when I deploy my react app on cpanel,
My react app is on cpanel and my backend(node js written) is on heroku

my function on react app

```
const adminLogin = (values) => {
    var formD = new FormData();
    formD.append('username',username)
    formD.append('password',apassword)
    formD.append('isAdmin',true)
    setLoader(true)
    axios.post("/api/login",formD).then((res)=>{

      if(res.data.status == 200)
      {
        
          // isAuthenticated()
          if(res !== undefined){
          // toastr.success(res.data.message)
         
        }
       
    })
  }
```

and my login function on backend creates and stores httponly cookie on successful login
It works successfully on localhost as I am using proxy field in package.json file but i am aware that it doesn't work on cpanel.

login function on backend

```
exports.login= (req,res)=>{
if(login logic success){
 if (cookie == undefined){

        
    res.cookie('admintoken', token, {httpOnly: true});
    return res.status(200).json({auth:true,"status":200,message:"login success"});
    
    }
}
}
```

and this is the proxy field in my packagejson file

```
"proxy": "https://backend.com"
```

All this works perfectly on localhost
and if i give complete url the on front end login is successful but cookie is not stored
so How can I store cookies(it will be used for maintaining user session).

**UPDATE**: I tried using htaccess redirect rule but it also didn't work

The thing that i am trying to have is making request to backend but url is of front end as i mentioned earlier basically a "proxy" and that is why it's not storing cookies.

Comment: What is the value of sameSite attribute of the cookie?

Comment: I haven't set that

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
Default is lax. this is why the cookie isn't set. Your react app is being served from a different domain

Comment: yes i made changes and instead of using proxy field in package.json, i made changes to axios call and set strict value to sameSite but it still doesn't work 
my backend is on heroku and frontend on localhost
if I try with backend on localhost as well then it works

Comment: It will not work with sameSite=strict, because your server and your frontend(you said it's served from some cpanel) on a different domain

Comment: yes, I set the sameSite:'none'

Comment: And does it work now? Note that sameSite=none carries possible security issues with it. I recommend you inquire the subject, there are many posts and blogs about it. Also, note that "herokuapp.com" is a "special" domain, treated differently by browsers: https://publicsuffix.org/. It basically means that even if you create a subdomain and serve your React from there, it will still be treated as a different domain by some browsers.

Comment: yes it works
i setup cookie like this
secure:true,sameSite:'none',httpOnly:true
and on cors i only whitelisted one frontend url and with credentials:true
will it still be security issue?

Comment: So, i'm far from an expert on the subject. you will need to inquire. From my understanding, sameSite=none can make your site vulnerable to CSRF attack: If a malicious site is open in the same browser, it can use your cookie(let's say, a login cookie). You should read about it. Generally, sameSite=none is not the best thing, unless you have another security mechanism in place, like maybe SCRF token.

Comment: Actually, I also used secure:true,httpOnly:true
and axios with credentials

Comment: Yes, but httpOnly means that the cookie cannot be accessed with JS. It still, however, is sent automatically by the browser, when it's supposed to be sent. CSRF attacks exploits this idea, by relying on this cookie being sent, when the attacker's site is open in a different tab, together with your site. "secure" means it can be sent only over https. As i said, i aint no expert, but from what i understand, sameSite=none makes CSRF technically possible.

Comment: Thanks for that, I will look into it.